# Better way to communicate the sentence "Unlabelled miscellaneous utterances"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I have utterances and they are all neatly labelled but I have a section for `Unlabelled miscellaneous utterances`
And I think that name is far too long, is there any better way to write this?

Comment: Is there any reason *miscellaneous utterances* or *unlabelled utterances* wouldn't work? The words *miscellaneous* and *unlabelled* seem redundant with each other.

Comment: Why not just “Other”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that's not a sentence, but a noun phrase. However, you also indicate it's a title, so that's fine.

---

I can think of no way of shortening this without losing some degree of detail that each word brings. However, if you are fine with losing a little bit of this detail, you could use the single word *miscellanea* rather than *miscellaneous utterances*.

The word [*miscellanea*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miscellanea) doesn't mean *miscellaneous utterances*. Instead, it's closer to *miscellaneous things*.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a collection of miscellaneous (see MISCELLANEOUS sense 1) objects or writings

Things that are miscellaneous are themselves things that are random, and things that are random might not be things that you'd necessarily apply labels to. In that case, depending on your context, it might not be necessary to use both words.

So, this might work:

> Unlabelled Miscellanea

Or even just this:

> Miscellanea

Alternatively, based on the possible synonymity of what you're trying to express between *unlabelled* and *random*, and if preserving *utterances* is essential in your case, you could also simplify it as this:

> Random Utterances